# Failure/Error: click_link post.title ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) Rspec & Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara, bdd

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe "Posts pages" do
  let!(:posts) { FactoryGirl.create_list(:post, 3) }
  subject { page }
  describe "Blog page" do
    context "Listing all posts" do
      before do
        visit "/blog"
      end
        it "should list all available posts" do
        posts.each do |post|
          page.should have_selector "h3 a", :text => post.title
          page.should have_selector ".content", :text => post.content
        end
      end
    end
  end
  describe "Showing a post" do
    let!(:post) { posts.last }
    before do
      visit "/blog"
      current_path.should == "/blog"
      click_link post.title
      save_and_open_page
    end

    it "should have post info" do
      should have_content post.title
      should have_content post.content
    end
  end
end
```

If I remove `click_link post.title` my code is working fine.

I'm using `capybara (2.1.0)`

**Why, where have I the error?**

Comment: error is `click_link posts.last` but it doesn't appear in the code

Comment: I have fixed the title text, there was an error in title. Thank you!

Comment: The error was with xpath gem version. With capybara 2.x it is necessary use xpath 2.x. Thank you!